MERN backend not working on other computers after deploying
I deployed my MERN stack app on Render. It's a flight management app and when I go to the website on my computer, I'm able to add new flight information and it displays it on the homepage. When I open the site on another computer it also displays the information I added, but when I try to add new flight data, it won't add it.
I originally thought it was an issue with MongoDB, so I allowed access from anywhere on it but that did not solve the problem.
This is my index.js:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const logger = require('./middleware/logger');

const cors = require('cors'); // Cross Origin Resource Sharing
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI);

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080; // Default to 8080 if not in .env
app.use(express.json()); // This is middleware that auto parses JSON into JS objects between each HTTP request and the endpoint
app.use(cors()); // Allow all traffic
app.use(logger);

// router connections
app.use('/flights', require('./routes/flight.route'));

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('We don\'t have the resource you\'re looking for.');
});

// database connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}!`);
});

I wondered if the issue could be related to the React frontend package.json pointing to local host proxy:
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8085"
}

I was wondering if I need to add the production api url to the .env but I've seen several tutorials where that wasn't needed.

Hi, Thank you for your question. It would help if you include a gist of the module flight.route as well. By the way, do you make use of cookies or any other types of client data store ?

Hi, please also post the error details if any with respect to the mentioning "...it won't add it..."

Thank you for your help. I am at work so I don't have my code in front of me but I went to my site and received this error in the console when trying to add flight data: POST http://localhost:8085/flights net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

So it's going to local host instead of the deployed url. Maybe I have to add an environment variable for production with the url. If that's the solution, is the only way to switch between development and production is by commenting out the code during each commit?

I just realized localhost:8085 is the frontend

Hi, Please see the post https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1087#issuecomment-262611096. gaearon has explained the same over there as proxy is just a productivity feature. By the way, the how do you serve your app ? Is it from the same origin wherein API is also hosted. This is the kind of setup they see ideal. process.env.NODE_ENV and a custom variables are the additional ways when the app has a different origin. Please take sometime to read the same. It gives more idea about it.

Great, thank you.

I was able to solve the problem after your suggestion of seeing what the console error was, by going on another computer and seeing it. Thank you

Thank you for your confirmation. On other matter, which solution do you opt to handle proxy configuration does not go to production users.

I just removed my proxy entirely.
